# Using the Thread Object reference calling a Method

Tags: java, multithreading

Can i call a Method on the Thread Object ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have changed the question.

> Can i call a Method on the Thread Object ??

The simplest way to do this is to use an ExecutorService and submit ia task to call a specific method.

---

For your original question.

> can i reconnect again ??

I don't know of any reason you can't.

> Please let me know what are the impacts of such approach ??

You may want to wait a short period as it could fail repeately and you don't want to spam the server or overload your machine.  I would add a

```
Thread.sleep(periodBetweenReconnectesInMillisSeconds); // or something sorter
```

A retry period of a few seconds e.g. 2000 may be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ya you can call method on thread object ...

but explain me in which way you want to use it?

Comment: You, are of course, correct. Both in your simple answer and misgivings about correct use of such a call. An example of good use would be a call with an object reference that queues the object to the thread on a producer-consumer queue that is private to the thread object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, as Thread object is an ordinary object. The single difference is that after you call `Thread.start()`, its `run()` method would be executed on different stack. This stack also is called a thread, which can cause misconception. You have to distinguish stack and `java.lang.Thread`, the latter being an interface to a stack. 
When you call any method, it is executed on the current stack, that is, on the stack where the caller method runs. This way you can invoke even `Thread.run()` - but again, it would execute sinchronousely, not in parallel.

Comment: I've never encountered a stack being called a thread, in several decades of using both. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @EJP Think what stack overflow means? When java.lang.StackOverflowError is thrown? How jre option -Xss is decoded? (stack size). So what stack means in all that cases?

Comment: Stack overflow means you have run out of stack. It is thrown by a thread. -Xss sets the stack size of the thread. I fail to see the relevance. None of it means that 'a stack is also called a thread'. It isn't. Most of it demonstrates the opposite.